# Task state is not persisted on backwards navigation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, persistence, blockly

For an Ionic app that works with Blockly, the task should be persisted.
This works well when a task has been completed successfully. However, this ends as soon as I go backwards in the navigation.
For saving the state of a successfully completed task I use the function `updateTask`.

How can the task be persisted when I move backwards in the navigation ?

The processing of the task takes place in the `solveTask` function.

```
async solveTask() {
  let solvedCorrectly = false;
  let result;
  let solution;

if (solvedCorrectly) {
        this.task.solution = solution;
        this.task.solved = true;
      }
      await this.storage.updateTask(this.task);
      if (solvedCorrectly) {
        await this.openSuccessAlert();
      } else {
        await this.openFailureAlert();
      }
    }
```

The

```
updateTask
```

persists with success with the state. However, it does not work when navigating backwards.

```
public async updateTask(task: Task) {
    const path = this.navParams.getPath();
    const indexToUpdate = path.tasks.findIndex(oldTask => oldTask.title === task.title && oldTask.description === task.description);
    path.tasks[indexToUpdate] = task;
    if (!path.inProgress && task.solved) {
      path.inProgress = true;
    }
    this.updatePath(path);
  }
```